# Akka pattern for handling asynchronous actions in receive

Tags: scala, asynchronous, io, akka

I have an Actor that receives metrics datapoints and periodically aggregates and persists them to disk. This latter operation does I/O, so i don't want to use a blocking operation. But if i switch it to asynchronous, how do i prevent other datapoints from being received before the aggregation is completed without blocking somewhere.

One pattern I've seen is to use `Stash`, something like this:

```
class Aggregator extends Actor with Stash {
  def receive = processing

  def processing: Receive = {
    case "aggregate" => {
      context.become(aggregating)
      aggregate().onComplete {
        case Success => self ! "aggregated"
        case Failure => self ! "aggregated"
      }
    }
    case msg => ??? // Process task
  }

  def aggregating: Receive = {
    case "aggregated" =>
      unstashAll()
      context.become(processing)
    case msg =>
      stash()
  }
}
```

The misgiving i have with this is that the completion of my aggregate action is simply a message anyone could send. As i understand, i cannot effect the "unbecoming" from within my Future's completion.

As a side note, I have not been able to determine whether completions like `onComplete` are somehow executed by the same dispatcher as `receive`, since if they are not, completions would break the single-threaded protections that actors otherwise offer.

Or is there a better pattern for completing actions that are not synchronous and immediate inside of `receive` while guaranteeing that my state cannot be altered until i complete? It seems this scenario anytime actor state deals with I/O of any kind (like a DB) and clearly you would want to avoid synchronous I/O if you can.

Comment: Forward those messages to a special actor who's job is only to save metrics. This way original actor will not throttle and metrics will be saved one by one

Comment: To address your concern that anyone could send the message. You could create a private case object in the companion object that would trigger the aggregation. 

Anyway the others idea to split it to many actors is truly worth doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your aggregator actor is currently doing two things: aggregating and storing. You can both solve your issue and simplify your system by splitting these two tasks. The [single-responsibility-principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) also applies to actors.

I'd create a dedicated actor for writing and a message class for holding the aggregated data. This actor sub-system should look like this:
[image: Aggregator-Store actor subsystem]

Ideally, the time it takes to write to disk is shorter than the aggregation interval, such that your system remains stable. In case of spikes, the DataStore actor's queue will server as buffer for messages to be written to storage.

Depending on your application, you might need to implement some form of ack & retries in case you want to ensure that aggregated data has been written.

Comment: You are right, the only time i care about preventing receiving new metrics is while i'm collecting values to aggregate, but the aggregation and persistence don't need to block the receiving of metrics, so the aggregate message is a fast in-memory operation that sends the values of to another actor. Still learning how to decompose my usual object models with injected dependencies into actors.